# SQl query to find the exact table for an isntance name

Tags: mysql

Can we map two tables of two different SQL database..

My requirement is i want to move a user contact from one perticular table of MySQL Server 1 to another MySQL Server 2 .

Can we directly map two different tables on two different MySQL Server.

Please suggest me any SQL query to help in this mapping

thanks
ratish

Comment: might want to include mysql in the subject or say mysql server instead of sql server to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like replication is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

within a query, you can't specify a different database SERVER. however, you can create a [FEDERATED table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html) that allows you to query another table on a different server.